# How to implement doubly linked list without using tail pointer

Tags: go, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Is it necessary to have a tail pointer in doubly linked list? How to implement doubly linked list insertion without tail pointer, what would be the time complexity if we do so.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the node you're inserting before or after, then complexity is O(1). You only set the pointers in the previous/next nodes to point to the new node, and set the pointers in the new node to the prev/next nodes. You also update the head pointer if insertion is to the beginning of the list.

If you do not have a tail pointer in a doubly-linked list (or singly-linked list) and you do not have a reference to the last element, then appending to the list becomes O(n) because you have to traverse the list to find the last element.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not necessary. Below are the time complexities for a doubly-linked list that does not utilize `tail` pointers.

**Prepending to a List:** O(1)

> (head <-> newNode <-> x)

**Inserting between two nodes in the List**: O(n)

> (head <-> x <-> newNode <-> y)

**Appending to a List**: O(n)

> (head <-> x <-> y <-> newNode)
>
> *Note*: Utilizing the `tail` of a doubly-linked list would make the complexity O(1)

---

**TL;DR**: No, it would function almost the same, except for less performant appending cases O(n).